# Re-enable S5WakeOnLan setting for Realtek NIC driver that's disabled and hidden by inf file

Tags: windows, drivers, wake-on-lan, realtek

To be able to wake up a PC from the S5 'shut down' state, the OS has to prepare the NIC during system shutdown. For Realtek NICs, this is done by the "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" driver, but only if the option `S5WakeOnLan` "Shutdown Wake-On-Lan" is enabled. This setting is located at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` in an unpredictable subkey between 0000 and 0012.

I have discovered that it's the driver's .inf file that controls what the default value for this option is, and whether it's even visible in the UI. In an old sample from 2008, the setting simply defaulted to '1' and was made visible for all models. Recent versions have categories for individual NIC models, like

- `[s5wol.reg]` - visible and defaults to '1'
- `[s5wol.reg]` - hidden and defaults to '0' (faulty? found in 2015-04-06)
- `[s5wolhidedisable.reg]` - hidden and set to '0'
- `[s5wolhideenable.reg]` - hidden and set to '1'
- `[s5wolhidetype2.reg]` - hidden and set to '2' ?!?!

I have done a survey of the PCs I manage, and found that I'm dealing with all of the above. Initially, I just manually set `S5WakeOnLan` to 1 and it worked just fine, for over a year. A few old Vista PCs *sometimes* hang during power-on or reboot, which may be the reason why Realtek disabled it (or it might be caused by something unrelated). I was not able to find relevant documentation.

The problem is that everytime the OS decides to reinstall the NIC's driver (upgrade to Win10, driver update, every major OS Update which seems to be twice a year), the setting reverts to default, and the PC can no longer be turned on remotely. I have already had to fix this several times across all the affected WIn10 machines, and it's turning out to be an ongoing burden.

Half a year is enough for me to forget that this is still a thing, so when it does happen, it screws up my maintenance schedule, since I have to wait a day+ for the PC to be turned on physically, then patch the registry remotely, then wait again for the PC to be turned off and on, so that the registry change takes effect. I'd like to get rid of this issue, but so far the only workaround I came up with is a Group Policy Registry rule that shoves `S5WakeOnLan = 1` into every one of those numeric subkeys.

Comment: I updated my dev machine from Win7 to Win10 about 2 weeks ago and couldn't get WOL to work since then (it still works with the Win7) and have been trying to get it working since then.  Your regedit worked!  I changed the S5WakeOnLan under CurrentControlSet from 0 to 1 and BINGO!  Thanks!  EDIT: Asus P9X79LE with Realtek GBE Ethernet.

Comment: All win10 PCs at the office had their power options' "fast boot" (HKLM HiberbootEnabled) reset back to 'enabled' a few days ago, probably by another automatic windows update. This also breaks WoL and makes the PCs crash during boot. I'd watch out for that too.

Comment: Oh, and forgot to mention. If your card is recent, the driver may be exposing the "Shutdown Wake-On-Lan" setting in the Device Manager UI. In that case, it's easier to just change it there, since it should make the setting persistent across driver updates. Your issue was probably caused by the win10 upgrade, since it removes all driver packages and deletes all settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long-term solution is to have Microsoft update the driver packages hosted on Windows Update servers, to versions new enough that they don't exhibit the problem anymore. As time passed, I have observed this actually happening, gradually. Today I concluded that all of my originally affected PCs now expose the setting in the driver UI. Some still default to disabled, but changes to the setting should now be retained across OS upgrades. So for me, the issue is resolved.

Though I still have no idea how to report faulty packages to Microsoft in a way that would get them fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but since I had the same problem, and didn't want to mess with controller settings on hundreds of pc's, I did the following in the loginscript for all pc's:

(1) export the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318} to a file

(2) use a search and replace program to update the values that are needed for WOL to work

(3) import the registry file

For us, the problem is permanently solved this way.

Comment: I mentioned that registry location in my post, but also mentioned that the number at the end was unpredictable. Some workstations had the active NIC at 0001, some at 0004, some at 0012. A simple import wouldn't work. Your 'search and replace' step, if done right, should be able to find the right subkey. I suspect a lot of complexity is hiding behind that step 2, might be a pain to implement. Also in my case, the old drivers on some pcs were completely missing the S5WakeOnLan entry, so I would have had to make it search for the NIC itself. And I would have to run the script on each startup.

Comment: Sorry, the unpredictable number is correct, I updated my reply, you can export the whole key, then it doesn't matter what number exactly it is. Regarding which S&R program to use, it should support regular expressions, I will add a suggestion when I get some time later today. And yes, we are doing it in a login script set on the domain controller, that runs on every pc after the user logs on. I suppose it will require that the user has administrator rights, which is the case for us, but perhaps not for you?

Comment: Ah I understand now. Yes this is certainly one way to do it, especially if it only needs to be done once, administratively. I'm in the lucky position that there aren't that many pcs, and that all the problematic ones had their driver package updated by Microsoft, or have been replaced by a newer pc.